# How to enable failover for a postgresql jdbc data source

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, datasource, websphere-liberty, failover

I have a data source defined in a Liberty application server for postgresql

```
<dataSource jdbcDriverRef="PostgreSQLDriver" ...>
  <properties password="..." user="admin" serverName="server" portNumber="2020" databaseName="dbname" ssl="false"
</dataSource>
```

I see that I can enable failover on a jdbc connection by specifying a url like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://host1:port,host2:port,host3:port/dbname
```

Is there any way that this failover url can be provided to a application server datasource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify any key/value pair on the `<properties>` element and Liberty will supply it to the vendor data source class.  In this case, the property would be `URL="jdbc:postgresql://host1:port,host2:port,host3:port/dbname"`

Also, note that in more recent versions of Liberty, there is a `properties.postgresql` which is specific to Postgres and better [documents](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.zos.doc/ae/rwlp_config_dataSource.html) the available settings for it.

Here is an example,

```
<dataSource jdbcDriverRef="PostgreSQLDriver" ...>
  <properties.postgresql password="..." user="admin" URL="jdbc:postgresql://host1:port,host2:port,host3:port/dbname" ssl="false"
</dataSource>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did give both properties and properties.postgresql a try with no luck. Seems like it should work though.

Comment: This is the correct solution. The driver I was using was an old version that did not support the URL as a data source property.